# PHP; assigning fgets() output to an array

Tags: php, arrays, file-io, fgets

I am attempting to assign the string returned by the `fgets()` function to an array in PHP. I have tried test strings and they work fine. I have also made sure that `fgets()` is returning items, but still no joy. Thinking that it may be a timing issue, I had the function run `onload` and that didn't work. My code is below; any help on this would be much appreciated.

```
function createDataArray()
    {
        global $resultsArray;

        $i = 0;
        $file = fopen("downloads/E0.csv","r");

        while(! feof($file))
        {
            $line = fgets($file, 4096);
            $resultsArray[$i] = $line; //This isn't working. Something is wrong with $line. It is a string, but it doesn't get assigned to the array.
            $i = $i + 1;
        }
        fclose($file);
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `$i = $i + 1;` you can simply us `$i++;`

Comment: Why do you use `global $resultsArray;` not `return $resultsArray;`?

Comment: `Isn't working` explains something. `Do something` - would this help you to solve it?

Comment: @BjörnKaiser: I could do this, but I don't think that is the problem :-)

Comment: Nope, it's not the solution, just wanted to mention that ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: I use the same array elsewhere so I would like to manipulate the same array. It may be best practice to return an array, but I don't think this is the issue. Replacing the line $resultsArray[$i] = $line; with $resultsArray[$i] = "Test" works perfectly, but is a bit useless.

Comment: @zerkms: In relation to your second comment, what do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

PLEASE return the array; do not use globals.

This fix should work:

```
function createDataArray()
    {
        $resultsArray = array();

        $file = fopen("downloads/E0.csv","r");

        while(! feof($file))
        {
            $line = fgets($file, 4096);
            $resultsArray[] = $line; 
        }
        fclose($file);

        return $resultsArray;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but is that the fundamental issue here? I'm not sure that it is (see my comment to zerkms above). I have done a bit of a hacky workaround using this code `$resultsArray[$i] = substr($line, 0, 250);` and this puts the first 251 characters into the array. Obviously, this is not great code and would I like to get to the bottom of the issue. Any thoughts? Barry

Comment: @user1094389: well, that is not possible. If assignment to `substr($line, 0, 250);` then assignment to `$line` should work either

Comment: well, here's the thing - if you're using the same `$resultsArray` globally how can you know that a specific index of the array isn't being sliced or overwritten somewhere else in your application?

Comment: @zerkms: That's what's confusing me so much! The total string length is ~350 chars. Is that too long? 251 characters doesn't work, but 250 does!

Comment: @BrianDriscoll: Because this is the only time I am writing to the array. Am I being completely stupid?

Comment: @user1094389: in php the string length is only limited by free memory amount. So, no, 350 is not much

Comment: @user1094389 out of curiosity, is there a newline at `substr($line,0,250)`? It wouldn't explain why `$resultsArray[] = $line` doesn't work, but it would explain why `$resultsArray[] = substr($line,0,251)` doesn't work.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll: No line breaks whatsoever. Anyhoo, it isn't a big deal; I have an end result that works and this is just a personal project anyway. Thanks for all your help. ps This is my first time posting on SO and it's great!