# Explode contents of a txt file into array

Tags: php, arrays, text-files, explode

I´m having trouble exploding contents of a .txt file (structure below):

```
    01Name 1 
    02whatever contents
    03whatever contents
    -------------------
    01Name 2
    02whatever contents
    03whatever contents
```

As you can see, the "delimiter" is "-------------------". Now, the question is: how to explode this file into an array, so I can search for a specific name and display that block´s contents? I´ve tried to explode like this:

```
  header("Content-type:text/plain");
  $file = fopen("cc/cc.txt", "r");


  while (!feof($file)) {
    $lot = fgets($file);
    $chunk = explode("-------------------",$lot);

    print_r($chunk);

  }

  fclose($file);
```

And got this as a result:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => 01Name 1 

    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 02whatever contents

    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 03whatever contents

    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => -------------------

    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 01Name 2

    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 02whatever contents

    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 03whatever contents
    )
```

when i wanted to get this as a result:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => 01Name 1
        [1] => 02whatever contents
        [2] => 03whatever contents

    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 01Name 2
        [1] => 02whatever contents
        [2] => 03whatever contents
    )
```

I´ve searched [PHP; assigning fgets() output to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479672/php-assigning-fgets-output-to-an-array) and [Read each line of txt file to new array element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159683/read-each-line-of-txt-file-to-new-array-element) , with no luck.

Any thoughts?

Comment: you can't explode a txt file, you can explode contents of txt file ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following

```
$result = array();
$file = explode("-------------------", file_get_contents("cc/cc.txt"));
foreach ( $file as $content ) {
    $result[] = array_filter(array_map("trim", explode("\n", $content)));
}
var_dump($result);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string '01Name 1' (length=8)
      1 => string '02whatever contents' (length=19)
      2 => string '03whatever contents' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array
      1 => string '01Name 2' (length=8)
      2 => string '02whatever contents' (length=19)
      3 => string '03whatever contents' (length=19)
```

You can take it further

```
$result = array();
$file = explode("-------------------", file_get_contents("cc/cc.txt"));
foreach ( $file as $content ) 
{
    foreach(array_filter(array_map("trim",explode("\n", $content))) as $line)
    {
        list($key,$value) = explode(" ", $line);
        $result[$key] = $value ;
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

Output

```
array
  '01Name' => string '2' (length=1)
  '02whatever' => string 'contents' (length=8)
  '03whatever' => string 'contents' (length=8)
```

Comment: Your first option did it! Now it's just a matter of looping through arrays...Thanks!!!

Comment: You accepted another answer not mine ... you can only accept one answer at a time

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should use [`file()`](http://php.net/file) to read and split up a file line-wise. That's a built-in specifically for that purpose.

Your check for `"-------------------"` fails because you didn't take the trailing linebreaks (`\r\n` etc.) into account. (Use `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` for the `file()` function as one solution). Though it might be better to use a regex here:

```
$lines = file($filename);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (preg_match('/^\s*---------+\R*$/', $line)) { ... }
}
```

A bit redundant this way, but more resilient.

You might as well read the whole file with [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) and split out text blocks with [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) instead.

Comment: Preg_split does not apply in this case..other than that, it works fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your file is consistently formatted, having three lines per block of data, you could simply parse it that way. Here I am creating a 2-dimensional array of the whole file:

```
<?php

header("Content-type:text/plain");
$file = fopen("cc.txt", "r");

$alldata = array();
$index = 0;
while (!feof($file))
{
    $alldata[$index]['name'] = fgets($file);
    $alldata[$index]['c1'] = fgets($file);
    $alldata[$index]['c2'] = fgets($file);
    fgets($file); // throw away delimiter line
    $index++;
}
fclose($file);  

print_r($alldata);
?>
```

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 01Name 1 
            [c1] => 02whatever contents
            [c2] => 03whatever contents
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 01Name 2
            [c1] => 02whatever contents
            [c2] => 03whatever contents
        )
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I just edited my txt file for readability... the actual text file have approx. 2800 lines... and the number of lines are inconsistent on each block..

Answer (score 0):

```
$c      = file_get_contents($file);
$lines  = explode("-------------------", $c);
foreach ($lines as $l) {
    if (strpos($l, 'keyword') !== false) {
        echo $l;
        die();
    }
}
```